# ParseFile data downloading causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Good day,

I have a problem with storing `ParseFile` to the local storage. My application downloads set of files from `Parse.com` cloud on background in order to keep it on device's local storage. This is because we need to access files when device is `offline`.

Problem is, that the downloaded ParseFile objects stay in memory and causes `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` on some devices.

It is possible to force to clear objects from `memory` (not from parse `localstorage` `cache`) to prevent this errors?

Thank you,
Jan Konečný